# Photoshop, please let go of my hard drive!

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, adobe-photoshop

For some reason Photoshop is preventing me from ejecting my external hard drives.

### None of the drives are set as a scratch disk

No files are even open.  This is on a MacBook Pro, Photoshop CS5 and an external drive connected via Firewire 800.  How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you had files open in Ps from those drives recently? I suspect Ps may be holding on to those files for some reason. Also, what version CS5?

Comment: I do actually keep some icons and stuff on the external

Answer (score 1):

Close Photoshop (if you need to end process, but should not be necessary, and will happen automatically)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the result of some save for web previews that were still in cache after the file was closed.  Those files contained parts that were originally stored on one of the external drives.